# Dockerfile failed to change user access

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I want to run jenkins on docker and change the user access so could read the SSH key and access  git.
Here is sample of the dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root 

COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins id_rsa $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins id_rsa.pub $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls -la $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh; chmod 600 -R $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh; ls -la $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh'
```

The output upon build is a success, access has been changed!

```
Step 3/3 : RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls -la $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh; chmod 600 -R $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh; ls -la $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh'
 ---> Running in 137d1a4f9f6d
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan  8 04:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan  8 04:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 1843 Jan  2 02:33 id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins  413 Jan  2 02:33 id_rsa.pub
total 16
drw------- 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan  8 04:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan  8 04:11 ..
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1843 Jan  2 02:33 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins  413 Jan  2 02:33 id_rsa.pub
Removing intermediate container 137d1a4f9f6d
 ---> 7d6334d2b044
```

However when I go inside the `/bin/bash` the access is set to default, the chmod was not working

```
jenkins@f49048ec8c88:/$ ls -al /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan  8 04:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan  8 04:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jenkins jenkins 1843 Jan  2 02:33 id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jenkins jenkins  413 Jan  2 02:33 id_rsa.pub
```

any idea why the behavior is this way?

Comment: Why are you copying both of these files? If you need Jenkins to be able to log in to other systems, it should only need the private key. If you need Jenkins to be able to log in to this system, you should only need the public key.

Comment: @tripleee yes, I have not yet fix the files copying, trying to figure out user's permission first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened because `$JENKINS_HOME` is defined as `VOLUME` in `jenkins:lts` base image. You can workaround this in any of the 3 ways

1. You can fix the permissions on host machine before building and it should work.
2. You can use multi stage build, change the permission and copy files from first stage

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts as base
USER root
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins id_rsa /tmp/ssh_keys/
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins id_rsa.pub  /tmp/ssh_keys/
RUN chmod 600 -R /tmp/ssh_keys

FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins --from=base /tmp/ssh_keys $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh
```

3. You can copy and change permissions of the files in a temporary directory as part of build. As part of your startup script(entrypoint), you can copy them from the temporary directory to actual directory.

Comment: I am using windows btw, do you know how to fix the permission?

Comment: @greenthunder I've updated the answer. You can use multi stage build and modify the permission in first stage.

Comment: I've edited the answer above.. need to do --chown in jenkins/jenkins:lts otherwise the permission after copy will be root.. everything works now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because the command /bin/bash is just for that session. If you want it to be permanent, put it inside .profile.

Comment: tried without /bin/bash 'RUN chmod' still the same.. what do you mean by .profile btw?

Comment: It's the startup file which Bash runs when you start it in interactive mode.