# Docker image folder permission is not getting updated

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

when trying to run a docker image (openproject) in ECS, we received an error "DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) for /var/openproject/pgdata folder"

```
#ls -l /var/openporject
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Jan  8 15:56 assets
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres 4096 Dec 19 08:40 pgdata
```

So we tried to update the permission for via dockerfile

```
FROM openproject/community:latest
#USER postgres
USER root

RUN chmod 700 /var/openproject/pgdata
RUN chmod 700 /var/openproject/assets
```

even after building the image the permission on the folder is not getting updated.

Build method docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  openproject:
    container_name: openproj_server
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://aws@postgresurl:5432/openproject
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=junksecret
```

Suggestions will be helpful

Update 1:

Trial 1:

Setting up permission through entrypoint.sh method failed with an error : **DETAIL:  File "/var/openproject/pgdata/PG_VERSION" is missing.**

```
FROM openproject/community:latest
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /app/docker/
RUN chmod +x /app/docker/entrypoint.sh

**entrypoint.sh**
chmod 700 /var/openproject/pgdata
echo "Giving 700(rwx) Permission to pgdata folder"
chown postgres:postgres /var/openproject/pgdata
echo "Setting up ownership to postgres user / group(*just to double ensure)"
```

Cloudwatch logs:

```
2020-01-08 20:34:59.734 UTC [54] FATAL:  "/var/openproject/pgdata" is not a valid data directory
2020-01-08 20:34:59.734 UTC [54] DETAIL:  File "/var/openproject/pgdata/PG_VERSION" is missing.
2020-01-08 20:34:59,735 INFO exited: postgres (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Trial 2:

Binding nonpersistent empty storage for containers in a Fargate task used latest openproject

```
**Fargate Task Def snip**
   "mountPoints": [
        {
          "readOnly": null,
          "containerPath": "/var/openproject",
          "sourceVolume": "openproject"
        }
```

Cloudwatch logs:

```
2020-01-08 21:50:51.686 UTC [226] FATAL:  data directory "/var/openproject/pgdata" has group or world access
2020-01-08 21:50:51.686 UTC [226] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
2020-01-08 21:50:51,776 INFO exited: postgres (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Trial 3:

Updated image with pgdata permission via entry point and again throws fatal error : **File "/var/openproject/pgdata/PG_VERSION" is missing.**

Cloudwatch logs:

```
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/var/openproject/pgdata/postgresql.auto.conf"
2020-01-08 22:12:52.404 UTC [228] FATAL:  "/var/openproject/pgdata" is not a valid data directory
2020-01-08 22:12:52.404 UTC [228] DETAIL:  File "/var/openproject/pgdata/PG_VERSION" is missing.
2020-01-08 22:12:52,494 INFO exited: postgres (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Unable to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both `/var/openproject/pgdata` and `/var/openproject/assets` are marked as VOLUMES in openproject Dockerfile. - https://github.com/opf/openproject-ce/blob/stable/8/Dockerfile

*Relevant snippet from Dockerfile*

```
<snip>
ENV APP_DATA_PATH /var/openproject/assets
ENV APP_DATA_PATH_LEGACY /var/db/openproject
<snip>
VOLUME ["$PGDATA", "$APP_DATA_PATH"]
```

So your RUN instruction that is changing permission won't persist after the build.

You can follow any of the following approaches to fix this:

1. You can modify the `entrypoint.sh` script of `openproject` to fix the permissions as part of startup.
2. You can create two volumes on host with proper permissions and mount them into `openproject` container.

---

See the following answer for similar discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59639759/5459201

Comment: ...which means you could fix the permissions by updating the `entrypoint.sh` script included in the openproject image.

Comment: @larsks. Yes. There are few other ways as well to fix this. I have linked a similar question in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. What is the alternate approach here? My scope is to use openproject with aws rds. But ecs in log this is reported as fatal

Comment: like @larks has suggested, you can update the entrypoint.sh file of openproject to fix the permissions.

Comment: Or you can also create the volumes on host in prior with proper permissions and mount them into openproject container.

Comment: @larsks & Shashank any pointers here to troubleshoot. Updated my question